# How to test a user's code?

Tags: c++, c, testing

My query is very basic one but just want to know the exact things which occur behind the bars and how. Lets say, I am given a question to code. User submits the code in any language(I'd like to go for C or C++ here specifically), now the code gets tested on various test files at the server side. How this happens? As I think and searched, there must be a code at the server side which must be accepting solutions(user's code) from the client in form of the file, then run that file on various test files(which will have all test cases according to the input and output specified in the problem description) and match the output. Is it? I think there is something else or something which I am mistaken.

If I have a very simple program to add two numbers, now I want to test the user's code, what exactly do I have to do? I am asking from the implementation point of view i.e. I want to actually do and test the same on my machine. Can someone please tell me from basic what all I should do?(Much the same way online judges do)

PS: I am not asking this for hosting any contest etc, just doing out of curiosity for learning.

Comment: It's pretty much as you say. Some script feeds input into your program, runs it, analyses the output. Not complicated. Regardless, telling you in great detail how they work would be akin to doing it for you, which is far too broad. Besides, you haven't stated any specific requirements.

Comment: Could you please just help me knowing in steps what all I need to put in, lets say I am just given the user's code, now what do I need to do with the code. Just telling sequentially what needs to be done will be really helpful. Please let me know what requirements you want, I'll add them.

Comment: Sorry but this is a Q&A repository not a mentoring scheme. Have you considered asking a friend or a colleague to sit with you for a few hours and walk you through the options?

Comment: Test that it works in the general conditions. Test that it works at the limits of the expected conditions. Test that if fails gracefully when just outside the edge conditions. Then try to break it with utterly absurd conditions. If it is your own program don't wait until the program is finished: you should thinking about how it works and how it fails, step by step.

Comment: Yeah, my main concern is, like I can accept user's code by writing php code, I wanted to do that in C++. How should I do that? Afterwards, I'll only need to make a file of user's code and generate output file and match with the same correct o/p files (on the server) and show the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would divide this into two sub goals

1. learning automated testing
2. setting up some application which allows the user to submit testcases, run the automated tests and reports feedback

You could start to get some deeper insight by setting up automated tests for some program in your favourite programming language.

Use a search engine to e.g. look for "automated c++ testing".

If you have managed setting up a few automated tests on a local machine, your could then progress with the second goal.

For example you could set up a Jenkins instance and learn how to add automated tests to it.

Comment: May be this query is answered in the above answer, but still I'd like to confirm this : my main concern is, like I can accept user's code by writing php code, I wanted to do that in C++. How should I do that? Afterwards, I'll only need to make a file of user's code and generate output file and match with the same correct o/p files (on the server) and show the result.

Comment: In general you would not analyze the submitted code, but you would observe what outputs it gives to input given by your test suite. If it produced expected outputs it would pass a test. If the submitted code is c++, which is usually compiled, your test suite has to include a build phase next to a test execution pase. This is what you have to do for a local automated test suite as well.

Comment: BTW It is no problem to implement a test suite in PHP, which tests C++ code, but you should invoke at least an available C++ compiler instead of writing one in PHP which would take a lot of time. :-) Please invest some time in automated testing first, there are many good enough tools out there.

Comment: Ohkay, Thanks. I'll go through it.